# Parse boolean search query back to array

Tags: javascript, parsing

Is there any easy way to parse the following string to array. I can convert array to string but no idea how to convert back to array.

```
 // Input
"Keyword1 Keyword2 (Keyword3 OR Keyword4) -Keyword5 -Keyword6"

 // Output
 [
     {
         all: ["Keyword1", "Keyword2"],
         any: ["Keyword3", "Keyword4"],
         not: ["Keyword5", "Keyword6"]
     }
 ]


 // Input
 "(Keyword1 Keyword2 (Keyword3 OR Keyword4) -Keyword5 -Keyword6) OR (Keyword7 Keyword8 (Keyword9 OR Keyword10) -Keyword11 -Keyword12)"

 // Output
 [
    {
         all: ["Keyword1", "Keyword2"],
         any: ["Keyword3", "Keyword4"],
         not: ["Keyword5", "Keyword6"]
   },
   {
         all: ["Keyword7", "Keyword8"],
         any: ["Keyword9", "Keyword10"],
         not: ["Keyword11", "Keyword12"]
     }
 ]
```

Comment: Do you think that reasking makes your question better?? What have you tried?

Comment: I got many downvotes for that question I thought, it's better to rewrite my question.  I am still trying to find a solution.

Comment: many downvoted...? the voting  counter is positive (currently)

Comment: Not for this question i asked the same question in different way...I thought rewrite my question in a better way @snap

Answer (score 3):

First things first:

1. I don't validate the input. This answer gives you an approach. You should validate the input, especially since you say it comes from the user :)
2. We will make use of the `matchRecursive` function from [this blog](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/javascript-match-nested).

This function will help us group the correct parentheses.

```
var matchRecursive = function () {
    var formatParts = /^([\S\s]+?)\.\.\.([\S\s]+)/,
        metaChar = /[-[\]{}()*+?.\\^$|,]/g,
        escape = function (str) {
            return str.replace(metaChar, "\\$&");
        };

    return function (str, format) {
        var p = formatParts.exec(format);
        if (!p) throw new Error("format must include start and end tokens separated by '...'");
        if (p[1] == p[2]) throw new Error("start and end format tokens cannot be identical");

        var opener = p[1],
            closer = p[2],
            /* Use an optimized regex when opener and closer are one character each */
            iterator = new RegExp(format.length == 5 ? "["+escape(opener+closer)+"]" : escape(opener)+"|"+escape(closer), "g"),
            results = [],
            openTokens, matchStartIndex, match;

        do {
            openTokens = 0;
            while (match = iterator.exec(str)) {
                if (match[0] == opener) {
                    if (!openTokens)
                        matchStartIndex = iterator.lastIndex;
                    openTokens++;
                } else if (openTokens) {
                    openTokens--;
                    if (!openTokens)
                        results.push(str.slice(matchStartIndex, match.index));
                }
            }
        } while (openTokens && (iterator.lastIndex = matchStartIndex));

        return results;
    };
}();
```

Next, this is the algorithm I would use based on the data you provided:

1. we determine if we have 1st kind of input or 2nd type, by simply checking if `str.startsWith("(")`;
2. we initialize the followings:

   - `groupedItems` for an array that will transform 2nd type of input into 1st type of input, so that we use the same code for both afterwards
   - `returnArr` for the returned data
3. We loop over the `groupedItems` and prepare an empty `keywordObj`
4. In this loop, we determine which are the `any` keywords by making use of the `matchRecursive` function and splitting the result after `' OR '` - the resulting items will be `any` items
5. For the rest of the keywords (`all` or `not`) we need to get to a single word - so we split again, this time after `" "`, the result of the split being an array of keywords
6. We loop over the keywords and determine if they are `not` keywords by checking if they start with `-`, otherwise we treat them as `all` keywords.

Here's the code for it:

```
function output(str){
  var groupedItems = [];
  if(str.startsWith("(")){
    groupedItems = matchRecursive(str,"(...)");
  } else {
    groupedItems.push(str);
  }
  var returnArr = [];

  for (var i = 0; i<groupedItems.length;i++){
    var keywordObj = {all:[], any:[], not: []};
    var thisGroup = groupedItems[i];
    var arr = matchRecursive(thisGroup, "(...)");
    if (arr.length != 1) throw new Error("unexpected input");
    keywordObj.any = arr[0].split(" OR ");
    var restOfKeywords = thisGroup.split(" (" + arr[0] + ") ");
    for (var j = 0; j<restOfKeywords.length; j++){ 
        var keyWords = restOfKeywords[j].split(" ");
        for (var k = 0; k<keyWords.length;k++){
            if (keyWords[k].startsWith("-"))
                keywordObj.not.push(keyWords[k])
            else 
                keywordObj.all.push(keyWords[k])
        }
    }
    returnArr.push(keywordObj);
  }
  return returnArr;
}

// input "(Keyword1 Keyword2 (Keyword3 OR Keyword4) -Keyword5 -Keyword6) OR (Keyword7 Keyword8 (Keyword9 OR Keyword10) -Keyword11 -Keyword12)"
// output [{"all":["Keyword1","Keyword2"],"any":["Keyword3","Keyword4"],"not":["-Keyword5","-Keyword6"]},{"all":["Keyword7","Keyword8"],"any":["Keyword9","Keyword10"],"not":["-Keyword11","-Keyword12"]}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You're Awesome. Let me check.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NXMoqo?editors=0012

```
{
  // test cases
  // const input = 'Keyword1 Keyword2 (Keyword3 OR Keyword4) -Keyword5 -Keyword6';
  const input = '(Keyword1 Keyword2 (Keyword3 OR  Keyword4) -Keyword5 -Keyword6) OR (Keyword7   Keyword8 (Keyword9 OR Keyword10) -Keyword11 -Keyword12)';
  // const input = '((Keyword1 OR Keyword2 OR Keyword3) Keyword4 Keyword6 -Keyword5 -Keyword7) OR (Keyword8 Keyword9 (Keyword10 OR Keyword11) -Keyword12 Keyword13 -Keyword14 -Keyword15)';

  const output = [];

  input.split(') OR (').forEach(group => {
    let trimmedGroup = group.replace(/^\(/, '').replace(/\)$/, '');
    let anyGroup = trimmedGroup.match(/\(.+\)/).join('').replace(/[OR\)\(]/g, '').match(/\w+/g);
    let notGroup = trimmedGroup.match(/-\w+/g).map(element => element.replace('-', ''));
    let allGroup = trimmedGroup.replace(/\(.+\)/g, '').replace(/-\w+/g, '').match(/\w+/g);

    output.push({
      all: allGroup,
      any: anyGroup,
      not: notGroup
    });
  });

  console.log(output);
}
```

Comment: how to include phrase here ?

like ->  
"Keyword One"  Keyword2

Answer (score 0):

can you check this

```js
var arr = [], obj = {any:[], not:[], all: []};
function splitString(str) {
 var object = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
  var strArr = str.split(" ");
  var i=0;
  while(strArr.length !== 0 && i<10) {
   newStr = strArr.splice(0, 1)[0];
    if(newStr.indexOf("(") != -1) {
     while(newStr.indexOf(")") == -1) {
        object.any.push(newStr.replace(")", "").replace("(", ""))
        strArr.splice(0, 1);
        newStr = strArr.splice(0, 1)[0];
      }
      object.any.push(newStr.replace(")", ""))
    } else if(newStr.indexOf("-") != -1) {
     object.not.push(newStr.substring(1).replace(")", ""))
    } else {
     object.all.push(newStr.replace(")", ""))
    }
    i++;
  }
  arr.push(object)
}

function convertToObj(string){
 if(string.indexOf(") OR ") !== -1){
  string.split(") OR ").forEach(function(str){
      splitString(str.substring(1));
    });  
  } else {
   splitString(string);
  }
}


convertToObj("Keyword1 Keyword2 (Keyword3 OR Keyword4) -Keyword5 -Keyword6")
convertToObj("(Keyword1 Keyword2 (Keyword3 OR Keyword4) -Keyword5 -Keyword6) OR (Keyword7 Keyword8 (Keyword9 OR Keyword10) -Keyword11 -Keyword12)")
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Can't say what user might input and so can't assume anything. The code may work for specified input but didn't work always because for example if user put two space in between OR your code will break.